# In a certain range of columns, drop all rows with only NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like this

```
        x  y1  y2  y3  y4
0   -20.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   -19.9 NaN NaN  20 NaN
2   -19.8 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   -19.7 NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   -19.6 NaN  10 NaN NaN
```

I want the program to drop all rows with only `NaN` values in columns `y1` to `y4`.

The output would be this:

```
        x  y1  y2  y3  y4
1   -19.9 NaN NaN  20 NaN
4   -19.6 NaN  10 NaN NaN
```

I tried `df.dropna(axis = 0, how = "all", inplace = True)` but this counts column `x` aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify your columns as `subset`:

```
df.dropna(subset=['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4'], how='all', inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
      x  y1    y2    y3  y4
1 -19.9 NaN   NaN  20.0 NaN
4 -19.6 NaN  10.0   NaN NaN
```